# Failed exporting df.to_csv using a variable name in the path

Tags: pandas, dataframe, path, export-to-csv

I am using a function `MyFunction(DataName)` that creates a pd.DataFrame(). After certain modifications to data, I am able to export such dataframe into csv with this code:

```
  df.to_csv (r'\\kant\kjemi-u1\izarc\pc\Desktop\out.csv', index = True, header=True)
```

Creating an 'out.csv' file which is overwritten everytime the code is run. However when I try to give a specific name (for instance the name of the data used to fill in the dataframe, for multiple exports like this:

```
 df.to_csv (fr'\\kant\kjemi-u1\izarc\pc\Desktop\{DataName}.csv', index = True, header=True)
```

I have this error:

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 MyFunction(DataName)**

I am new in the programming world so any ideas of how I can overcome this problem are very welcomed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do explain the ```f``` in ```fr``` in your statement: ```df.to_csv (fr'\\kant\kjemiu1\izarc\pc\Desktop\{DataName}.csv', index = True, header=True)```

Comment: Dear Serge I am not sure if 'fr' makes sense. This was just my attempt to use formatted string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right (and given that the `fr` in your code should be simply `r`), you want to have your `to_csv` statement dynamic and what is supposed to go within the brackets to change. So, assume you dataframe if `df`. Then, do this:

```
DataName  = "df"
NewFinger.to_csv (r'\\kant\kjemi-u1\izarc\pc\Desktop\{}.csv'.format(DataName), index = True, header=True)
```

Comment: This was exactly my point, I would like to have a dynamic export of my df whose name matches the name of the list I am using to import the data in the first place. I tried your suggestion however VS code do not like this rr' either. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Remove one r. This was a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. In the beggining I was confused with 'NewFinger' I thought it was some sort of module I needed to install. I could not find information in google. However I solved the issue based on your suggestion actually with the following code:

```
DataName  = "whichever name"
df.to_csv (r'\\kant\kjemi-u1\izarc\pc\Desktop\{}.csv'.format(DataName), index = True, header=True)
```